# Word ordering in subclause "die Sache wäre entschieden gewesen"

Tags: grammar, word-order

From *Der Spiegel*:

> Andererseits bleibt das Spiel durch Prags Halbherzigkeit offen; hätten die Kommunisten etwa die Wasserversorgung der Vertretung mit Hinweis auf einen "technischen Defekt" gekappt, die Sache wäre entschieden gewesen.

Normally one would expect

> ..., wäre die Sache entschieden gewesen.

Is there some reason this particular word ordering might be preferred here? Is it considered "correct"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the two possibilities:

> (1) Hätten die Kommunisten die Versorgung gekappt, die Sache wäre entschieden gewesen.
>   (2) Hätten die Kommunisten die Versorgung gekappt, wäre die Sache entschieden gewesen.

There is no doubt that version (2) is a correct sentence consisting of a main clause followed by a subordinate clause.
Personally, I would use a different style of punctuation in version (1):

> (3) Hätten die Kommunisten die Versorgung gekappt... Die Sache wäre entschieden gewesen.

In my perception, version (1) and (3) evoke a little hesitation after the first part. The speaker/author makes a little pause to (let you) think about the consequences. Then the consequences are mentioned; however, not a subordinate clause is used but a main clause because that's a new thought.
Somehow this is like if the sentence was started without knowing where it should lead. Then there's a pause after which the original sentence is not completed but instead, a new main clause follows.

I think this can be compared to the following sentence structures:

> (4) Ich verstehe diese Gleichung nicht, weil... ich hab mich noch nicht mit diesem Mathe-Thema beschäftigt.
>   (5) Ich glaube Peter ist heute krank, obwohl... vielleicht macht er auch nur blau.

In examples (4) and (5) there is a little pause between the sentences where the speaker thinks about what should follow. Since this pause acts like a hiatus, the second sentence in each example shows a main clause structure instead of a subordinate clause structure that one would expect if the sentences were properly connected without a pause.

Comment: Mit einem Gedankenstrich --- statt Pünktchen ... wäre der Originalsatz auch leicher verständlich.

Comment: I think a colon (:) would be even clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually both is correct. But the sentence *Der Spiegel* used is the same like

> und die Sache wäre entschieden gewesen

But you can leave the *und* away. Might just be easier to understand with *und*.

Also their example is commonly used as kind of conclusion, a consequence.

Hope I could help