# Word order in relative clause "Es gibt Flüchtlinge, denen hilft die Bundesregierung"

Tags: grammar, word-order

Title and subtitle of an article from [*Süddeutsche Zeitung*](http://www.migazin.de/2014/11/12/eugh-hartz-iv-nsu-auslaender/):

> **Immer Richtung Norden**
>
> Es gibt Flüchtlinge, denen hilft die Bundesregierung, nach Deutschland zu kommen. Und es gibt solche, die sich alleine von Nordafrika bis an den Rhein durchschlagen – Männer wie Ibrahim und Wesam. Unser Reporter hat sie begleitet.

Normally, in a relative clause one would expect

> Es gibt Flüchtlinge, denen die Bundesregierung hilft, ...

It seems unlikely the the author wants a [little pause after the first part](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17226/word-ordering-in-subclause-die-sache-w%C3%A4re-entschieden-gewesen), because there is really nothing much to think about, given only "Es gibt Flüchtlinge". Why is the word order as it is then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es handelt sich um einen m. E. immer häufiger werdenden „Verbzweitnebensatz“, wie in

> Da liegt ein Mann, dem hilft keiner.

im Gegensatz zu der „klassischen“ Verbletztversion

> Da liegt **ein Mann, dem keiner hilft**.

Dass dies möglich ist und sich auch richtig anhört, liegt wohl an dem generellen Trend der deutschen Sprache, Haupt- statt Nebensätzen zu verwenden (s. „weil“).

Das funktioniert jedoch nicht immer; beispielsweise bei den Negationen ebendieser Beispiele:

> <strike>Da liegt kein Mann, dem hilft keiner.</strike>
> Da liegt kein Mann, dem keiner hilft.
>
> <strike>Es gibt keine Flüchtlinge, denen hilft die Bundesregierung, […]</strike>
> Es gibt keine Flüchtlinge, denen die Bundesregierung hilft, […]

**Stylistically**, the newspaper’s choice is more pleasant imho, because it makes you expect the infinitive group more than the verb-last version does.

Comment: Vielleicht eine Folge der Anglisierung der deutschen Sprache? Oder von mangelnder Sprachkompetenz generell?

Comment: @PMF Also in diesen Fällen finde ich die Verbzweitvariante gar nicht so schlimm, vielleicht sogar angenehmer. Bei "weil" hört es sich allerdings schrecklich an. In puncto Anglisierung: Womöglich handelt es sich um einen natürlichen Vereinfachungsprozess, den das Englische lediglich schon früher durchmachte.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Diese Variante hier ist nicht so schlimm wie bei "weil", aber sie hört sich für mich immer noch falsch an. In der Umgangssprache macht man ja gerne mal einen Nebensatz zum Hauptsatz oder hängt zwei Hauptsätze einfach so hintereinander, aber in der Schriftsprache stört es mich.

Comment: @dirkt Als ich den Satz aufschrieb, war ich zugegebenermaßen kurz verunsichert - beim Aufsagen (fast keine Pause zwischen "Mann" und "dem") stimmte dann aber wieder alles.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Bei mir ist es andersherum: Nur wenn ich eine lange Pause mache (wie bei einem Punkt), stimmt es. Als zwei Hauptsätze geht es, als Haupt- und Relativsatz mit Komma klingt es einfach falsch.

Comment: @dirkt: Die Antwort klingt, als wären die beiden Varianten gleichbedeutend. Das sind sie jedoch nicht, wie gerade durch die Negation deutlich wird. Der Relativsatz mit der "Verbletztversion" schränkt den Gegenstand des vorherigen Satzes ein bzw. spezifiziert diesen "innerhalb derselben Aussage". Der "Verbzweitnebensatz" ist hingegen eine neue Aussage nach dem Hauptsatz, die durch die Trennung per Komma nur etwas enger an den Hauptsatz gekoppelt ist. Deshalb funktioniert in letzterem Fall auch die Negation nicht, da die zweite Aussage eben nicht den ersten Gegenstand (der in diesem Fall ...

Comment: ... negiert ist) einschränkt, sondern eine zusätzliche, neue Aussage zu diesem Gegenstand liefert, und da der Gegenstand in der negierten Aussage eben nicht vorhanden ist, ergibt es keinen Sinn, eine zusätzliche, neue Aussage dazu zu machen. Deshalb lässt sich diese Konstruktion meines Erachtens überhaupt nicht mit "weil" vergleichen, sondern allenfalls mit zwei vollkommen separaten kurzen Hauptsätzen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich bleibe dabei, dass ein "Verbzweitnebensatz" für mich einfach falsch klingt, ob man ihn nun mit einem schönen Namen und semantischen Unterschieden aufhübscht oder nicht. Entweder ein Punkt und zwei Hauptsätze, oder ein Komma und Haupt- und Nebensatz. Sprache verändert sich natürlich, und vielleicht sind in 100 Jahren "Verbzweitnebensätze" normal; aber nach meinem Sprachempfinden geht es nicht.

Comment: @dirkt: Dagegen habe ich nichts einzuwenden. Mir ging es nur darum, dass die Gegenüberstellung mit Relativsätzen meines Erachtens nicht viel Sinn ergibt (und mit Nebensätzen, die mit "weil" eingeleitet werden, erst recht nicht), da einfach etwas anderes ausgedrückt wird. Somit ist es nicht weiter verwunderlich, wenn sich Relativsätze und die sogenannten "Verbzweitnebensätze" nicht analog verhalten.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the second part is not writen (as it would usually be) as a subordinate clause but as main clause. This emphasizes the verb "helfen" as it moves further to the beginning. Of course, the structure with the other order is valid, too.

Concatenating main clauses like here is valid because one can replace the first comma with a period as well:

> Es gibt Flüchtlinge. Denen hilft die Regierung,...